# How to get the selected radio button value from five radio buttons in android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I need to get the selected radio button value out of 5 radio buttons. I have done like :

**Radio button values from db:**

```
op1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option1);
op2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option2);
op3=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option3);
op4=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option4);
op5=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.option5);
System.out.println("after lv users ");
op1.setText(listItem.getOption1());
op2.setText(listItem.getOption2());
op3.setText(listItem.getOption3());
op4.setText(listItem.getOption4());
op5.setText(listItem.getOption5());
```

**RadioButton check action:**

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int checkedId) {
 for(int i=0; i<radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
 System.out.print("radiogroup child counts");
 System.out.print(radioGroup.getChildCount());
 op1 = (RadioButton) radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
 if(op1.isSelected()== true) {
  System.out.println("radio i value");
  System.out.print("option"+i);
  //String text = btn.getText();
  // do something with text

    }
  }
 }
});
```

But it is not working.It is showing error as `NullPointerException` at line

```
op1.setText(listItem.getOption1());
```

Where I went wrong?

Help me regarding this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`NullPointerException` means that one of these objects (`op1` or `listItem`) is null.

Try debugging your code to find the null object.